# submit can't send data of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

Recently I study html and javascript.
I know that in html form sends data to server
between  and .

However, in my case it doesn't.

here is my code

```
function wReply() {
             if(document.getElementById("repInputContent").value == "")  {
                alert("type anything for reply");
                document.getElementById("repInputContent").focus();
                return;
             }
             document.reply.submit();
        }
```

this is javascript function that work with input type button.

And this is html form code

```
<tr id="replyInput">
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <form action="/wReply" accept-charset="utf-8" name="reply" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<%=num%>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="writer" value="<%=writer%>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<%=page%>">
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="repInputContent"></textarea>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="wReply()"></td>
            </tr>
```

I code a table and want to send hidden type datas and textarea data.
I think it works but actually server can receive hidden type datas.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textarea needs a name.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="repInputContent" name="repInputContent"></textarea>
```

That'll fix you up.

Comment: I've gotten so used to frameworks doing my forms that when I tried to create a simple form myself i forgot about this silly thing and wasted a few hours debugging something else...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `function wReply(){ ... }` is inside `body` tag instead of `head`! Then
Submit button sends data correctly.
As I have tried it myself;

1. [***This JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/z2n1zow4/5/) doesn't work, because script is in `Head` of the form.

[image]

2. And This is [**Wroking Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/z2n1zow4/4/), where script `function wReply(){ ... }` is inside `body` of the form!

[image]

Comment: Thank for your sincere answer.
I'll test it now!

Comment: You mean that function should be in `<body>`? Or between `<form>` and `</form>`?